# Regex Expression to allow comma only inside a string (within quotes)and not outside it

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am kind of new to regex. I am looking for a regex expression to add it as a constraint not to allow comma outside a string .

My input is like

```
"1,212121,121212","Extra_data"
```

Here the regex expression should not check for comma in the first value within quotes `"1,212121,121212"` but should check after the quotes including `,"Extra_data"` . In short expression should allow comma in a string only inside quotes and not outside.

Kindly help me with the expression.

Comment: Trying to understand more; that means `"1,212121,121212","Extra_data"` is an invalid string?
Also, can the valid string contain only a comma and nothing else?

Comment: Hi Pramod, The expression should make it invalid . Yes it can have only comma and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, essentially a group of numbers or commas surrounded by parentheses then followed by comma and another phrase (not necessarily numbers) in parentheses.  Capturing group #1 gives you "1,212121,121212"  and capturing group #2 gives you ,"Extra_data"

```
("[\d,]+")(,"[^"]+")
```

It would be helpful to see more of how your input might come in.  I think that the biggest question that remains is whether that first group always contain only numbers/commas, or are there sometimes other characters such as letters, underscores, etc in that first group?  If that first group contains only numbers, as I've assumed, then this should work.  If it doesn't, then this will not work.

Edit:

```
"\s*(,\s*"[^"]+")
```

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for the expression. As you said group 1 is not necessarily numbers and it can be any string with commas in between.

Comment: @VigneshJei: I updated the expression based on what you said and based on what I'm thinking you are after.  Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Let me make it simple Jon. We dont want the group 1 to be checked and the expression should check only from the comma after group 1

Comment: @VigneshJei: Just added another regex to try.  Does it work?  If not, why not?

Comment: @VigneshJei: or  `"(?:^|"\s*)(,\s*"[^"]+")` allows for the possibility that the string opens with a comma.  This expression and the last one assume several things. 1. That neither quoted group ever contains solely a comma, and 2. That the group to the right of the outside comma is always surrounded by quotes

Comment: Thank you Jon... The above one works \s*(,\s*"[^"]+")

Comment: @VigneshJei:  Great.  Note that `\s*(,\s*"[^"]+")` assumes several things.  It assumes that the input string never opens with an outside comma, that the quoted groups never contain only a comma, and that the quoted group after the outside comma always has a pair of quotes and is never empty.  If any of this is not true, some adjustments would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
".*?(?=,).*?"
```

it only extract comma in a string only inside quotes

Comment: input:"1,212121,121212","Extra_data" ;
"1,212121,121212","Extra,data"    output:"1,212121,121212","Extra,data" ?

Comment: Input is "1,212121,121212","Extra_data"
Output should allow only "1,212121,121212" and throw constraint error as " ,"Extra_data" "

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
"[^"]*"(,)[^"]*"[^"]*"
```

It will capture the commas you need. But note that PHP has no support for captures of the same groups. i.e. in your case:
If the input is : "1,212121,121212","Extra_data","hel,lo","a,bc"
It will capture commas before "Extra_data" and "a,bc" but will exclude the comma before "hel,lo". For that you'll have to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regex.

```
(^,)|("\s*,\s*")|(,$)
```

If you find any match for this regex, then the string will be invalid.